# mysql select combination of rows based on value

Tags: mysql

I have got an employee master table where I have field named 'Gender'. I want to select total 10 records from employee master table where I should get 5 records of Gender as Male and 5 records of Gender as Female. How can i do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for some hints on writing a good-quality question.

Answer (score 2):

You can try like this:

```
select * from employee where Gender = 'Male' LIMIT 5
UNION ALL
select * from employee where Gender = 'Female' LIMIT 5;
```